# Two functions that get data from a FireBase database, and a third function that performs some calulations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two functions that successfully retrieve integers from Firebase.  I'd like a third function that does some simple subtraction from the integers gathered in the first two functions.

However, I'm very new to this, so can't get it to work correctly.

The output of the two functions that gather data from Firebase are:

```
let pointsRedeemedAsInt:Int = Int(Points_Redeem)!
```

and

```
let sumOfPointsCompleted = self.challengeList.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.Points}
```

What I'd like is a third function that looks like this:

```
let pointsBalance = sumOfPointsCompleted - pointsRedeemedAsInt
```

However, the third function doesn't recognise sumOfPointsCompleted, nor pointsRedeemedAsInt.

// First Function:

```
 func loadPointsRedeemed() {


    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    databaseReference.child("Users").child(userID!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        // let Points_Earn = value?["Points_Earned"] as? String ?? ""
        let Points_Redeem = value?["Points_Redeemed"] as? String ?? ""


        // self.Points_Earned.text = Points_Earn
        self.Points_Redeemed.text = Points_Redeem

        let pointsRedeemedAsInt:Int = Int(Points_Redeem)!

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

)}
```

//Second Function:

```
func LoadPointsCompleted() {

    self.challengeList.removeAll()

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let refChallenges = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Challenges").child(userID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Complete")

    refChallenges.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.challengeList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for Challenges in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let challengeObject = Challenges.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let Points = challengeObject?["Points"] as! Int

                //creating challenge object with model and fetched values
                let challenge = pointsModel(Points: (Points as Int?)!)

                //appending it to list
                self.challengeList.append(challenge)

                let sumOfPointsCompleted = self.challengeList.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.Points}

                let sumOfPointsCompletedString = String(sumOfPointsCompleted)
                self.Calc_Earned.text = sumOfPointsCompletedString
            }   
        }
    }   
    )}
```

// Third Function (which does not work):

```
 func BalanceOfPoints(){

    let balance = sum - pointsRedeemedAsInt

}
```

The error is:

> Use of unresolved identifiers sum and pointsRedeemedAsInt

Furthermore, how do I ensure that everything is executed in the right order? ie, the loadPointsCompleted function must run (and complete) first, followed by the loadPointsRedeemed function, and finally the BalanceOfPoints function.

Comment: You are trying to access variables that are outside of the scope of the method. That cannot be done. Try to read the swift docs before continuing so you have a better idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that you are not considering that retrieving data from remote sources is asynchronous.
This means that you have to wait for data to be retrieved before calling the other functions.

To achieve this result, you should use swift closure (callback in other languages) with completion handler. Check [this documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Change your functions this way:

First Function

```
func loadPointsRedeemed(completion: @escaping (_:Int)->()){

databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

databaseReference.child("Users").child(userID!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    // let Points_Earn = value?["Points_Earned"] as? String ?? ""
    let Points_Redeem = value?["Points_Redeemed"] as? String ?? ""


    // self.Points_Earned.text = Points_Earn
    self.Points_Redeemed.text = Points_Redeem

    let pointsRedeemedAsInt:Int = Int(Points_Redeem)!

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Call your return back function called "completion"
    completion(pointsRedeemedAsInt)

}

)}
```

***Second Function***

```
func loadPointsCompleted(completion: @escaping (_:Int)->()){

self.challengeList.removeAll()

databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

let refChallenges = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Challenges").child(userID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Complete")

refChallenges.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //if the reference have some values
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

        //clearing the list
        self.challengeList.removeAll()

        //iterating through all the values
        for Challenges in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            //getting values
            let challengeObject = Challenges.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let Points = challengeObject?["Points"] as! Int

            //creating challenge object with model and fetched values
            let challenge = pointsModel(Points: (Points as Int?)!)

            //appending it to list
            self.challengeList.append(challenge)

        }   

        let sumOfPointsCompleted = self.challengeList.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.Points}

        let sumOfPointsCompletedString = String(sumOfPointsCompleted)
        self.Calc_Earned.text = sumOfPointsCompletedString

        completion(sumOfPointsCompleted)

    }
}   
)}
```

***Third Function***

```
 func balanceOfPoints(completion: @escaping (_:Int)->()) {
   loadPointsCompleted{(sum) in
        //HERE YOU CAN USE THE RESULT OF loadPointsCompleted
        //I CALLED IT sum

    loadPointsRedeemed{ (pointsRedeemedAsInt) in
          // HERE YOU CAN USE THE RESULT OF loadPointsRedeemed
           //I CALLED IT pointsRedeemedAsInt
          let balance = sum - pointsRedeemedAsInt
          completion(balance)
     }       
 }

}
```

To call the balance function wherever you want:

```
       balanceOfPoints{ (balance) in
           // Whatever you want with balance
       }
```

If you change the view ( for example you set some label text ), be sure to use the functions in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access variables outside the scope of `BalanceOfPoints()`.

Try returning the values you want to use in the equation from the first two functions, `loadPointsRedeemed()` and `LoadPointsCompleted()`. This can be done like so:

**First Function**

```
func loadPointsRedeemed() -> Int {

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    databaseReference.child("Users").child(userID!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        // let Points_Earn = value?["Points_Earned"] as? String ?? ""
        let Points_Redeem = value?["Points_Redeemed"] as? String ?? ""


        // self.Points_Earned.text = Points_Earn
        self.Points_Redeemed.text = Points_Redeem

        let pointsRedeemedAsInt:Int = Int(Points_Redeem)!

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        return pointsRedeemedAsInt

    }

)}
```

**Second Function**

```
func loadPointsCompleted() -> Int {

    self.challengeList.removeAll()

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let refChallenges = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Challenges").child(userID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Complete")

    refChallenges.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.challengeList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for Challenges in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let challengeObject = Challenges.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let Points = challengeObject?["Points"] as! Int

                //creating challenge object with model and fetched values
                let challenge = pointsModel(Points: (Points as Int?)!)

                //appending it to list
                self.challengeList.append(challenge)

            }   

            let sumOfPointsCompleted = self.challengeList.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.Points}

            let sumOfPointsCompletedString = String(sumOfPointsCompleted)
            self.Calc_Earned.text = sumOfPointsCompletedString

            return sumOfPointsCompleted

        }
    }   
)}
```

**Third Function**

```
func balanceOfPoints() -> Int {

    let sum = loadPointsCompleted()
    let pointsRedeemedAsInt = loadPointsRedeemed()

    let balance = sum - pointsRedeemedAsInt

    return balance

}
```

Now, wherever you call the functions `loadPointsRedeemed()` and `loadPointsCompleted()`, replace these calls with `balanceOfPoints`.

Notice the main changes I made to your code are adding return values to your functions so they can be used in other areas of your code. Check out the [Swift Functions Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks Mathyou, tried this but now get the following error:

Unexpected non-void return value in void function.

Comment: @nm1213 You're missing the return type in the declaration of each function. Look at the samples I wrote again. At the end of each function, between the `()` and `{`, I have a ` -> Int`. This means the function must return an integer. Not having this means the function expects a void return value, in other words, none at all.